# How should the prevalence be calculated when determining prevalence-adjusted PPV?

Tags: precision-recall, case-control-study, prevalence

I am assessing the performance of a test for a certain disease. I have selected the disease cases and controls from a large dataset that is reasonably representative of the general population.

As I have enriched my test dataset for disease cases, I'm adjusting for prevalence when calculating the PPV of the test, using `PPV = (Sensitivity × Prevalence)/[(Sensitivity × Prevalence) + ((1 - Specificity) × (1 - Prevalence))]`

However, the prevalence of this disease isn't well-known, and a range of values is reported in the literature. I can instead calculate the prevalence from the dataset that I selected my cases and controls from, but the data isn't perfect, and some of these will be mislabelled.

When calculating the PPV, is it more appropriate to use prevalence from literature, or prevalence calculated from the dataset I'm testing?